# Background Image repeats on Rotation for split second

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I've set my background image to adjust when the device is rotated using the code below and it works fine (picture is stretched on landscape but thats ok) except for the fact that when it rotates, for a split second, the picture repeats itself before rescaling to fill the view.

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainBackground.PNG"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];


}
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainBackground.PNG"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

}
}
```

I thought maybe using "willanimaterotation.." would possibly cover this up but it is still noticeably irritating.

Being pretty new to all of this is there anyway to correct this/am i going about this totally wrong? At a guess I think i possibly need a way to scale the image before it rotates but i'm unsure how to code this or if its even possible.

At the moment the only way i can personally think to fix it is to create 2 separate image files for portrait and landscape which i dont really want to do.

Comment: you can use an imageview

Comment: Whilst your answer was brief it spurred me on to figure out how to use an ImageView and it is now fixed so thanks haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImageView` is the way to go here.

Note that your use of `if` conditions in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` are returning the same result each time. Furthermore, using this method is unnecessary. Instead, let `AutoresizingMask` manage the presentation of your views.

Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainBackground.PNG"]];
    [imageView setAutoresizingMask: (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I managed to figure it out this way after all but you've just confirmed i've done it correctly! As a quick side question, I only included 'UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight' with it being a background is there advantage to me including the flexible margins as it works fine with just height/width as it stands?

Comment: Glad you found your solution. If `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` provides the result you're looking for, there's no added advantage to the other options. Margins come into play when resizing against other components.